# How to get the version of flutter and dart programatically?

Tags: flutter, dart

It would be nice to find out what version of flutter and dart my app was compiled under.  Is there any way to get this programatically?

Comment: I am not sure about flutter but running `Platform.version` should give you the dart version, don't forget to `import dart:io`

Comment: Thanks @EdwynZN, it seems to work in android but not web, I'm a little closer.  Thank you

Comment: I haven't read it in detail but the reason why Platform.version doesn't work on the web looks to be related to this open Flutter issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39998